# Why does Ariandel keep the flame from going out?

Tags: dark-souls-3

"I see flame. Flame, flickering, once again. Not enough blood yet shed. My flail... Bring me my flail..."

Why does Ariandel keep the flame from flickering? Isn't that what he and Friede wanted in the first place? Why doesn't he let it flicker and die?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was misunderstanding Ariandel's intention and sentence... Here's the answer if anyone is interested:

> It's largely out. If it begins to flicker, then he needs to provide
>   more blood to put it out again...not to get it going. Likely it's
>   flickering due to the chosen ash being near.

There's [a short discussion at Reddit for this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/darksouls3/comments/5l454j/why_does_ariandel_keep_the_flame_from_going_out/).